# Horizontal spacing between imageView and label in a horizontal stackView

Tags: ios, uistackview

[image]

How to get horizontal spacing between imageView and label in a horizontal stackView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add horizontal spacing using "spacing" property in Attributes inspector.

[image]